# Not able to make daily time series analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, forecasting

The following is my data,

```
 day       sum
2015-03-05   44           
2015-03-06   46           
2015-03-06   48           
2015-03-07   48           
2015-03-08   58           
2015-03-09   58           
2015-03-10   66           
2015-03-11   68           
2015-03-12   85           
2015-03-13   94           
2015-03-14   98           
2015-03-15  102           
2015-03-16  102           
2015-03-17  104           
2015-03-17  114
```

The type of variables used are as follows,

```
typeof(x)
[1] "list"

typeof(x$day)
[1] "double"

typeof(x$sum)
[1] "integer"

class(x$day)
[1] "Date"
```

I want to predict, for a particular future date, what would be the sum.

The following are my findings,

When I use ts(x), the values of the dates are changing as follows,

```
day

16464              

16465              

16466

16467

16468

16469

16470

16471

16472
```

When I use ets, following is the output,

```
fit <- ets(x)
Error in ets(ana) : y should be a univariate time series
```

I am able to plot the dates with the sum and getting the graphs perfectly. But, I am not able to make any analysis after this point. I want to predict, for a particular future date, what would be the sum. I tried regression analysis also, but it doesn't work with this variable. Can anybody please help me how to proceed further?

Thanks

Comment: Read [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Working%20with%20Time%20Series%20Data%20in%20R.pdf) manual:

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13880/how-can-i-predict-values-from-new-inputs-of-a-linear-model-in-r   --> Also, there are two values for some days, e.g., 46 and 48 for 2015-03-06. This is only possible if these are measures at two separate times during that day. If so, that needs to be considered when model building.

Comment: @InNoam Thanks for the post. Yes I am working on bringing the time also to the variable. But I am getting the following errors,

q<-lm((as.POSIXct(x$day,"%Y-%m-%d"))~x$sum)

predict(q,data.frame(x$sum=c(3000)))

Error: unexpected '=' in "predict(q,data.frame(x$sum="

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here. Can you please help me here?

Comment: If you search for equality, it is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: > predict(q,data.frame(x$sum==3000))


         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 

It is throwing some random values and not able to understand.

Comment: This is different from your original post. Please open a new one with this specific problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can use any forecast package or ts function? Why am I not able to use these variables? Does the datatype of the variables matter here?

Comment: Please pay careful attention to the comments and instead of posting code in comments instead post  as edits to your question. The answer to the question "does the datatype matter?" is almost always YES! The R language is completely driven by datatypes.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you "correct" the duplicated days, you will be able to do this:

```
library(xts)
dates=as.Date(x$day,"%Y-%m-%d")
xs=xts(x$sum,dates)
plot(xs)
library("forecast")
class(xs)
fit <- ets(xs)
plot(forecast(fit))
```

[image]